# Will a 802.11a WiFi antenna will work with an 802.11n router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I found [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/5-8G-200mW-11dBi-Panel-WiFi-Video-Audio-A-V-Antenna-TX-More-Than-3KM-FPV-3YE-/271631552959) on eBay, it's cheap and it says it can go to 3km range but the problem is...
"Applications:
•1).For Long Distance FPV Wireless Video Transmission
•2).WiMax, 802.11a WiFi Networks, and 802.16 WiMax Networks
•3).Public Wireless Hotspot
•4).Wireless LAN Systems"
I don't know if 802.11a or 802.16 would work over 802.11n routers. Would this antenna work with a N router?

If not, would it work as an antenna with [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Signal-King-150Mbps-USB-WIFI-Wireless-Adapter-Network-LAN-Card-48DBI-Antenna-/201146068086)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Look at the frequency. 2.4 GHZ is not the same as 5600-5900MHZ. It will most likely still work, but the gain will be below specifications, which defeats the purpose of buying one in order to extend range.

Look at this to see which frequency is used by which protocol: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11#Protocol

Comment: It would only work if the 802.11n router was set to 5.0ghz but even if it did the entire network would run at 802.11a speeds

Comment: @Ramhound That's not how antennas work. If you use an antenna at a different frequency it still works, but the gain is (sometimes considerably) less, depending on the frequency and the antenna type. I highly doubt the antenna has a filter built in, that belongs into the router. And if the router would use 802.11n at 5 GHZ, I see no logical reason why a different antenna would change that to 802.11a speeds, please explain.

Comment: It is also important that the impedance match the router. Also that of any cable used to connect the two.  Some N routers also seem to use multiple antennas so the one shown needs to go on the primary antenna. Most vendors specify this in the manual.